# Long delay when pushing a UIViewController

Tags: ios

I have run into a strange issue where pushing a custom UIViewController is resulting in a long delay before my controller appears. If I change my code to present the controller instead of pushing it there is no delay.

I am not doing anything fancy when I create and push my VC:

```
MyCustomViewController *myView = [[MyCustomViewController alloc] init];
NSLog(@"myView init done");
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:tagsView animated:YES];
NSLog(@"myView PUSHED");
// switching this to [self presentViewController:myView animated:YES completion:nil] gets rid of the delay
```

I have added a number of logs to try to identify exactly when the delay is taking place. The NSLogs from above print quickly as expected:

```
myView init done
myView PUSHED
```

Then there is a long delay, probably 20-30 seconds, before all of these lines print:

```
ViewController loadView begins
ViewController loadView ends
ViewController viewDidLoad begins
ViewController viewDidLoad ends
ViewController viewWillAppear begins
ViewController viewWillAppear ends
willShowViewController
ViewController viewDidAppear here
didShowViewController
```

All of the ViewController logs are obviously from my UIViewController and `*ShowViewController` ones are from my UINavigationController delegate. All of the methods of my viewController seem to be running quickly. As I mentioned, if I instead present this same controller at this point in my code there is no delay. Is there a state my UINavigationController can be in to cause this? Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is this being done inside some sort of completion block? Make sure you are pushing the view controller on the main thread.

Comment: Hmm… It seems as if the problem lies in the 1st view controller because the problem only happens when you maintain your navigation stack… Are there any tasks that may be running in the 1st view even after you attempt to push the 2nd view controller?

Comment: The code posted in my question is being called from a method run when my ViewController observes a notification. I did not realize this causes it to run outside of the main thread. I tested wrapping it in `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{...})` and the delay goes away. Thanks so much for the help!